# How to convert and Execute lib_file.a Library file in Command prompt?

Tags: c, shared-library, autocmd

I have a lib_file.a library file which is a static library and it is converted from .c file.

I know how to compile and execute .c files. But I dont know how to execute Library .a file using command prompt.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Library files are not executable.  They are used by executables.

Comment: Why do you want to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute .a library  files, they are used by executables.

Instead you can convert your **.a** file into **.exe** file and then you can execute it.

open command prompt and move to the path where your source file exists.

**Conversion of .a file into .exe file:**

```
gcc library_file.a -o executable_file
```

**Execution of executable_file:**

```
./executable_file
```

Now the file is executed. :)

Answer (score 2):

A static library, which is what a file called `something.a` usually is, is not a file that you may run from the command line.

It contains library routines that may be called by some other application, and is linked in with the rest of the code as one of the steps in the process of compiling that application.